# Equivalent of 'this' inside lambda function

Tags: javascript, jquery, lambda, arrow-functions

I have a function like:

```
$(".myDropdown").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".myDropdown-caretDown").hide();
}, function() {
  $(this).find(".myDropdown-caretDown").show();
});
```

If I want to use lambda function for hover callback, What can I use instead of `this`?

Comment: `this` inside arrow function is the same object as `this` in the scope that defines the arrow function

Comment: One of the main ideas of arrow function is that `this` is not redefined from the parent context. If you need `this` don't use arrow functions.

Comment: @Igor I believe that's why OP's asking the question. OP, my question is simply... *why?* Why go out of your way to do something that will require more work and isn't meant for that purpose? If I were following up a project and saw someone use arrow functions for event bindings I think I'd pull my hair out.

Comment: @Mhd: I was confused by the question until I've read the comments: You _are_ using _lambda functions_, that's anonymous functions, i.e. functions without a name. Your question seems about _arrow functions_, which are also anonymous functions but with a different syntax and semantic regarding the value of `this`. Maybe you should edit the question and title accordingly to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`this` inside arrow function is the same object as `this` in the scope that defines this function:

```
$(".myDropdown").hover(
  e => $(e.target).find(".myDropdown-caretDown").hide(),
  ...
});
```

Comment: For this specific example, I can use event, but in general way, I can't use lambda function?

Comment: "can't use lambda function" - for what?

Comment: Use lambda function and get access to `this` that refers to this function

Comment: @Mhd You use a lambda/arrow function specifically when you *don't* want a local `this`, hence my comment above about this being a questionable approach.

Answer (score 3):

> What can I use instead of this?

Use `event.target`

```
$(".myDropdown").hover('click', (event) => {
    $(event.currentTarget).find(".myDropdown-caretDown").hide();
  },(event) => {
    $(event.currentTarget).find(".myDropdown-caretDown").show();
  },);
```

Comment: In more general way, I can't use lambda function if I need `this` of local function?

Comment: @Mhd with *lamda function*, scope of `this` is defined by  the object that defines this *lamda function*. So, in your case it will belong to the function that defines this `hover` event-handler.